# Store function Varables and Prevent them from being set to their initial values on page_load

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I need to navigate between some records that I have in a database.

For example, I have a prev-record button on my page which navigates back by one record.

But as soon as I click the button, the page_load is fired first thus setting my function variables to their initial values.

Thus I can use the button only once. The second time I use, it will navigate to the same record.

I need a way to store the value of the variable after the function is executed and reuse this value again.

I am a beginner.

Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieve in different ways.
You can keep the old value in viewstate or in query stirng and next time you can check it.

But if you are using gridview you can go through the below example
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/67520/GridView-Paging-and-Sorting

view state example
http://aspnet-with-c-sharp.blogspot.in/2010/12/viewstate-with-example-in-aspnet-c.html

Comment: Hello, Does viewstate store the values dynamically?
Could you give me some links to help me learn its usage ?
Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 0):

In your page load, only set the function variables if Page.isPostback is false. This will prevent the values from being reset on a postback. eg.

```
If (!Page.isPostBack)
{
  //Set initial function variables
  // also store the initial values, possibly in session
}
```

When you navigate to the next record, store the previous record values in session. Then when you you go to the previous record, use the session value.